# Delay while loading Default.png

Tags: iphone

I think that in my app loading of Default.png takes more time than usual. So is there constant time from launching to appearing of first view when Default.png displayed? Or maybe it depends on memory that app uses? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The time of the defaut.png loading is totally dependent on the  load you have put up on the applicationDidFinishLaunching.. So try not to call much function from there. As soon as your above function is done... It will end up the display of default.png...

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the time taken by your view to load.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the load in the appDidFinishLAunching function in the application delegate.. IT will load fast..

hAPPY iCODING...